# In NgFor cycle with NgIf

Tags: angular, angular-template

I am doing angular and from backend I have data. Data looks like:

```
{
 name: 'Name',
 surename: 'Surename',
 position: 'Goalkeeper'
},
{
 name: 'Name',
 surename: 'Surename',
 position: 'Defender'
}
```

And in HTML I have:

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let player of players" [value]="player">
  <div *ngIf="player.position === 'Goalkeeper'">
             {{player.name}} {{player.surename}} ({{player.price}}M)
  </div>
</mat-option>
```

But in result, I get free space after players, who is not in condition ngIf ...
In real, looks like:

[Image of mat-option in web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cmu9v.png)

I add lines to better see free space on image.

What should I repair to remove free space? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach suggested by Jota is very solid.

Anorher way would be to create a property in component class that would already have goalkeepers.

```
get goalkeepers() {
    return this.players.filter(p => p.position === 'Goalkeeper');
}
```

Then you could iterate over them

Comment: Clearly, the better way to keep logic out of your template. But be careful with getters that are doing intensive tasks, because they are called on each CD cycle, better filter the `players` array when `players` is set.

Comment: Thanks, it is work :-) And can you help me with explain my problem? When I choose choice in one player and send to database (I use MongoDB), I see only this: 
{
goalkeeper: "[Object: object]"
}

But when I add to database text, all is good. What sould I repair?

Comment: @Ali I think it would be better if you asked another question with all the details, you could add a link to this question as a reference :)

Comment: Yes I already did it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55010771/from-mat-select-save-data-to-database-mongodb . Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `mat-option` is rendered independent of the player, only its content change.

Refactor as follows:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let player of players">
  <mat-option *ngIf="player.position === 'Goalkeeper'" [value]="player">
    {{player.name}} {{player.surename}} ({{player.price}}M)
  </mat-option>
</ng-container>
```

The perfect solution would be to use `ngFor` and `ngIf` in the `mat-option`, but its not possible to apply 2 structural directives on the same element. Due to this, you need to "expand" the template into the above.

Comment: Thanks, it is work :-) And can you help me with explain my problem? When I choose choice in one player and send to database (I use MongoDB), I see only this: { goalkeeper: "[Object: object]" } But when I add to database text, all is good. What sould I repair?