# From mat-select save data to database MongoDB

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express

I have collection Player and collection Teams. I want to add load players to teams.

in HTML in create Team, where I load data from players and user can choose load players:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Goalkeepers" formControlName="goalkeeper">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let player of goalkeepers" [value]="player">
      {{player.name}} {{player.surename}} ({{player.price}}M)
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
  <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('goalkeeper').invalid">Pleasse enter a goalkeeper.</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

And in user.component.ts I save data.
Here is load data from players to HTML:

```
 this.playersService.getPlayersForTeam();
    this.playersSub = this.playersService
    .getPlayerUpdateListener()
    .subscribe((playerData: {players: Player[]}) => {
      this.players = playerData.players;
    });
```

And here is save data to database:

```
onSaveUserTeam() {
      this.userTeamsService.addUserTeam(
        this.form.value.name,
        this.form.value.goalkeeper,
        this.form.value.goalkeeper_sub,
        this.form.value.midfielder1,
          ... etc ...
      );
```

I sent data to database without errors. When I had only this inputs:

```
<input matInput type="text" formControlName="goalkeeper" placeholder="UserTeam goalkeeper">
  <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('goalkeeper').invalid">Please enter a userTeam goalkeeper.</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

So like text, when I write something to input and then send to database, all was good. But now, when I have mat-select with players from player collection, I get in  database something like this:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId('5c7ecdd75c09e23d903f1bb9')
  name: "Test"
  goalkeeper: "[object Object]"
  goalkeeper_sub: "[object Object]"
}
```

And it is a problem, because I need to have same specific player detail like playerID to use later for edit team etc...
What I do wrong in seding data to database?
Thanks for you help!

Comment: I would suggest checking first what data is sent to service and if it has correct structure.

Comment: In team.service, I have something like this: https://ctrlv.cz/shots/2019/03/05/T1rh.png

Comment: Is there a reason you use form data instead of JSON payload? :) Check Network tab in Chrome (or equivalent in your browser of choice) and see what actual payload is being sent.

Comment: I am sorry, do you mean this? https://ctrlv.cz/shots/2019/03/05/3EaC.png , or this? https://ctrlv.cz/shots/2019/03/05/VFop.png

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Angular serializes objects not in a way it's supposed to serialize. Maybe you're passing incorrect values from your form to this method.

I would suggest you to refactor `addUserTeam` method so that it would accept a single object that needs to be uploaded and completely remove form data.

```
addUserTeam(userTeam: UserTeam) {
    this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/userteams', userTeam);
}
```

Where `UserTeam` is a class/interface that contains all the properties attached in the screenshot.

Comment: Well, do you mean, that conain of this function https://ctrlv.cz/shots/2019/03/05/T1rh.png , should I move to new class (new file? ) and then use in place of screenshot your recommend function?

Comment: I don´t know, If I did all good, but when I send data, nothing do.

UserTeams: https://ctrlv.cz/shots/2019/03/06/Piu7.png
Function to send: 
1 . https://ctrlv.cz/shots/2019/03/06/Zbi6.png
2. Definition in function: private userteams: UserTeams;

What is bad, please?

Comment: How does network request look like when you submit this?