# How to start bootstrap carousel in angular from a specific index after source array changed

Tags: angular

I have a bootstrap carousel in an Angular component. 
The items are loaded with ngFor from an array.
Under the carousel I have some thumbnails.
What I need to do is when the user is clicking on one thumbnail, the carousel will receive the same array but modified as source, with different images and larger then the first array and start the carousel from a different index(index of the thumbnail from below), not from 0. 
The problem is when I am clicking on the thumbnail for the first time(when the source changes), the carousel always starts from 0, not from the index that I am sending with $('.carousel').carousel(idx).
How can I fix this?

```
<div class='carousel-item' *ngFor="let img of carouselGallery" let i = index"
    <div class="carousel-item-image">
        <img [src]="img.src" alt="{{img.alt}}" class="slide-image">
    </div>
</div>

<li *ngFor="let image of gallery; let j = index" 
(click)="switchImageList(j)">
    <img [src]="image.src" alt="{{image.alt}}">
</li>

switchImageList(idx: number) {
    this.carouselGallery.length = 0;
    this.carouselGallery = this.galleryImages.slice(); // copy the larger gallery
    $('.carousel').carousel(idx);
    $('.carousel').carousel('cycle');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**ngFor** doesn't listen for changes in the source because it doesn't bind to the source variable. This, it renders only once before the function is called and doesn't change any more. Use **ngIf** to disable that list and enable after the function is called.

You can also follow [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55008924/in-ngfor-cycle-with-ngif) answer.

Comment: Not working with ngIf. I added the code for the carousel too to see better the issue...

Comment: If you want to re-render with ngIf, then you set the variable null and then set new value, or it won't work.